# Bind a key to show autocompletion

Tags: notebooks, user-interface, interface, autocomplete, predictive-interface

I've searched for a feature which is usually available in most IDEs where you are able to de-activate autocomplete and by pressing a key, usually Tab, the autocompletion pops up and you can either decide to choose from any of the available entries, usually by using the arrow keys and Tab again, or keep writing.

Does Mathematica have this functionality built-in or could it be hacked somehow?

Comment: Try Ctrl/Cmd + K.

Comment: Great, that works after you check either "AutoPopupEnable" or "ShowCodeAssist" in the Option Inspector menu. Given that it was you that provided the answer, would you mind answering it directly so that I set it as the solution? 

As a followup question, is the keyboard shortcut modifiable somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer: Ctrl/Cmd + K, after you check either "AutoPopupEnable" or "ShowCodeAssist" in the Option Inspector menu.

ihojnicki has posted the solution to this question has a comment, and not has an answer.  I will create an answer just to mark this has solved and if in the meantime he does create an answer I'll select his over mine.

Comment: You can have the points. +1